# Pandas GroupBy with special sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have data like that and I want to group them in terms of feature and type.

```
feature  type    size
Alabama  1       100
Alabama  2       50
Alabama  3       40
Wyoming  1       180
Wyoming  2       150
Wyoming  3       56
```

When I apply `df=df.groupby(['feature','type']).sum()[['size']]`, I get this as expected.

```
                size
(Alabama,1)     100
(Alabama,2)     50
(Alabama,3)     40
(Wyoming,1)     180
(Wyoming,2)     150
(Wyoming,3)     56
```

However I want to sum sizes with only the same type not both type and feature.While doing this I want to keep indexes as (feature,type) tuple. I mean I want to get something like this,

```
                size
(Alabama,1)     280
(Alabama,2)     200
(Alabama,3)     96
(Wyoming,1)     280
(Wyoming,2)     200
(Wyoming,3)     96
```

I am stuck trying to find a way to do this. I need some help thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex` and then [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for return same length `Series` by aggregate function:

```
df = df.set_index(['feature','type'])
df['size'] = df.groupby(['type'])['size'].transform('sum')
print (df)
              size
feature type      
Alabama 1      280
        2      200
        3       96
Wyoming 1      280
        2      200
        3       96
```

EDIT: First aggregate both columns and then use `transform`

```
df = df.groupby(['feature','type']).sum()
df['size'] = df.groupby(['type'])['size'].transform('sum')
print (df)
              size
feature type      
Alabama 1      280
        2      200
        3       96
Wyoming 1      280
        2      200
        3       96
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want however, it leaves data with same indexes so data is bigger than I expected. Is there a way to remove duplications of same index? (All same indexes have same size value)
pandas.Index.drop_duplicates did not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
df['size'] = df['type'].map(df.groupby('type')['size'].sum())

df.groupby(['feature', 'type'])['size_type'].sum()

# feature  type
# Alabama  1       280
#          2       200
#          3        96
# Wyoming  1       280
#          2       200
#          3        96
# Name: size_type, dtype: int64
```